# VScode color customization of css bracket not working

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colors, scope, customization

I want to change the color of the `{` symbol in CSS code, but it is not working.
See the `{` in css code below:

[image]

In the code above, "{" seems like yellow, even though I applied customization code in settings.json file.

My code is

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Sonokai]:{
            "textMateRules":[{
                "scope":[
                  "punctuation.section.property-list.begin.bracket.curly.css",
                  "meta.property-list.css",
                  "source.css",
                  "meta.embedded.block.html",
                  "text.html.derivative"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground":"#D7D8DBE7"
                }
              }
            ]
```

I found that no matter what color I write in `"foreground":"..."`, it always shows the same color.
Applying the color setting to only `punctuation.section.property-list.begin.bracket.curly.css` scope also didn't work.

Comment: Disable this setting: `Editor > Bracket Pair Colorization: Enabled`.  Or change the colors yourself with the setting `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` and `"editorBracketHighlight.foreground1"` etc.